# How much the libgit2 test failed? (How should I interpret the results?)

Tags: visual-c++, libgit2

I have fetched/merged the last changes from the libgit2 repository (the commit 4ae29053d5), created the `build` subdirectory, and compiled the library on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010 this way:

```
e:\Software\libgit2\build>cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 10" -DTHREADSAFE=ON -DSTDCALL=OFF
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.40219.1
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
zlib was not found; using bundled 3rd-party sources.
-- Found PythonInterp: c:/Python26/python.exe (found version "2.6.5")
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/Software/libgit2/build

e:\Software\libgit2\build>cmake --build .

Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 10.0.40219.1.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Checking Build System
1>  CMake does not need to re-run because E:/Software/libgit2/build/CMakeFiles/g
enerate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>------ Build started: Project: git2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>------ Build started: Project: libgit2_clar, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

2>  Building Custom Rule E:/Software/libgit2/CMakeLists.txt
2>  CMake does not need to re-run because E:\Software\libgit2\build\CMakeFiles\g
enerate.stamp is up-to-date.
2>  precompiled.c
3>  Building Custom Rule E:/Software/libgit2/CMakeLists.txt
[...]
3>  renames.c
3>  submodules.c
3>  lookup.c
3>  status.c
3>  basic.c
3>  trace.c
3>     Creating library E:/Software/libgit2/build/Debug/libgit2_clar.lib and obj
ect E:/Software/libgit2/build/Debug/libgit2_clar.exp
3>     Creating library E:/Software/libgit2/build/Debug/libgit2_clar.lib and obj
ect E:/Software/libgit2/build/Debug/libgit2_clar.exp
3>  libgit2_clar.vcxproj -> E:\Software\libgit2\build\Debug\libgit2_clar.exe
4>------ Build started: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>  Building Custom Rule E:/Software/libgit2/CMakeLists.txt
4>  CMake does not need to re-run because E:\Software\libgit2\build\CMakeFiles\g
enerate.stamp is up-to-date.
4>  Build all projects
========== Build: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Everything seems OK. When launching the test, it fails:

```
e:\Software\libgit2\build>ctest -V
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :E:/Software/libgit2/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
UpdateCTestConfiguration  from :E:/Software/libgit2/build/DartConfiguration.tcl
Test project E:/Software/libgit2/build
Constructing a list of tests
Done constructing a list of tests
Checking test dependency graph...
Checking test dependency graph end
test 1
    Start 1: libgit2_clar

1: Test command: E:\Software\libgit2\build\Debug\libgit2_clar.exe "-ionline"
1: Test timeout computed to be: 9.99988e+006
1: Loaded 195 suites:
1: Started
1:
1: attr::file....
1: attr::flags...
1: attr::ignore.....
[...]
1: status::submodules......
1: status::worktree..................................
1: status::worktree::init........
1: submodule::lookup.....
1: submodule::modify....
1: submodule::status.......
1: threads::basic.
1: trace::trace......
1:
1:   1) Failure:
1: diff::workdir::submodules [..\tests-clar\diff\workdir.c:825]
1:   33 != exp.lines
1:   33 != 35
1:
1/1 Test #1: libgit2_clar .....................***Failed  250.12 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) = 250.20 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - libgit2_clar (Failed)
Errors while running CTest
```

Is it a know situation? It seems that a lot of (sub)tests passed. I do not know the test framework. Does the messages at the end mean that only the `diff::workdir::submodules` failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know the test framework.

Libgit2 relies on the **[Clar](https://github.com/vmg/clar)** test framework.

> Does the messages at the end mean that only the diff::workdir::submodules failed?

Yes. More precisely, it points you to the **[failing assertion](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/tests-clar/diff/workdir.c#L825)**

> Is it a known situation?

No. The libgit2 team works hard to always have the tests passing.

I've tried locally and I cannot reproduce this issue. This **[gist](https://gist.github.com/nulltoken/5928977)** contains the build and test run against **[libgit2@4ae29053](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/4ae29053d51968cbf49f30ae14e5405cbd9543cc)**.

This has been run on Win 7 (32 bits) platform against Visual Studio 2010 as well.

The only difference I see is that you're running an older version of Python, but that shouldn't be a problem. **[Clar](https://github.com/vmg/clar)** relies on Python to generate the test suite (more info about this in the **[README](https://github.com/vmg/clar/blob/master/README.md)** file of the project) and supports Python back to version 2.5.

If you can successfully reproduce this failure, please open an issue in the **[libgit2 issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues)** as this may require a more deeper troubleshooting that may not fit to the StackOverflow format.